# Unable to connect Fortify Scan Central Controller with SSC (Softare Security Center)

Tags: security, fortify

For my Organizantion i have upgrade Fortify Scan tool version from 18.20 to 20.1.0. Post upgrading the binaries in local server for Scan Central Controller, I am able to access controller from local at address "http://servername:8080/scancentral-ctrl/" but the same is not accessible from my workstation. Also while trying to Integrate Fortify SSC with ScanCentral Controller I am unable to view the controller status. I have added the url details under Configuration Tab on Fortify SSC portal.

The Config.properties file has been updated in ScanCentral install with the required details.
Please suggest any fix/insight on the issue.

Comment: This question belongs more to https://serverfault.com/ than stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks @MarekPuchalski - i will check there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your client.properties file in your Fortify installation folder at Core\config? It should have the client_auth_token paramater value set with the same token in the config.properties file found in your controller installation folder at tomcat\webapps\scancentral-ctrl\WEB-INF\classes.